# ¿Como obtener la informacion en un select dependiendo lo que haya seleccionado de otro select?

Tags: mysql, angularjs

Ando realizando un crud de empleados, en el formulario de creacion de empleados  tengo 2 select. El primer select es el de departamentos por lo tanto despliega por ejemplo (Dpt. Auditoria, Informatica, Bodega, etc). Y el segundo select es el de puestos, por lo tanto me devuelve todos los puestos que existan.

```
//Select departamentos
        $scope.ObjDepartamentos = {};
        $scope.departamentos    = [];

        $http.get(server+'ws/departamentos').success(function(datas)
        {
            angular.forEach(datas.records, function(value, key)
            {   
                $scope.departamentos.push({
                    id:         value.id,
                    title:      value.nombre,
                    value:      value.id,
                    parent_id:  value.id 
                });
            });
        });

        $scope.ObjDepartamentos['departamentos'] = $scope.departamentos;

        $scope.confDepartamentos = {
            create: false,
            maxItems: 1,
            placeholder: 'Departamentos...',
            optgroupField: 'parent_id',
            optgroupLabelField: 'title',
            optgroupValueField: 'ogid',
            valueField: 'value',
            labelField: 'title',
            searchField: 'title'
        };
        //----------------------
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" config="confDepartamentos" options="ObjDepartamentos.departamentos" ng-model="item.iddepartamento" name="iddepartamento" selectize />
```

Segundo select:

```
//Select puestos
            $scope.ObjPuestos = {};
            $scope.puestos    = [];

            $http.get(server+'ws/puestos').success(function(datas)
            {
                angular.forEach(datas.records, function(value, key)
                {   
                    $scope.puestos.push({
                        id:         value.id,
                        title:      value.nombre,
                        value:      value.id,
                        parent_id:  value.id 
                    });
                });
            });

            $scope.ObjPuestos['puestos'] = $scope.puestos;

            $scope.confPuestos = {
                create: false,
                maxItems: 1,
                placeholder: 'Puestos...',
                optgroupField: 'parent_id',
                optgroupLabelField: 'title',
                optgroupValueField: 'ogid',
                valueField: 'value',
                labelField: 'title',
                searchField: 'title'
            };
            //----------------------
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" config="confPuestos" options="ObjPuestos.puestos" ng-model="item.idpuesto" name="idpuesto" selectize />
```

**Quiero saber como: al momento de seleccionar por ejemplo el departamento de informatica en el segundo select unicamente me muestre los puestos que estan relacionados al departamento de informatica, cabe mencionar que en otra tabla creo los puestos relacionados a un departamento.**

Answer (score 0):

Qué tal amigo.

Probablemente no sea necesario realizar dos llamadas a recursos. En la primera llamada podrías devolver un objeto JSON con un formato semejante a:

```
[
    {
        nombre: "Auditoría"
        puestos: ["Director", "Gerente", "Auditor de Sistemas"]
    },
    {
        nombre: "Informática"
        puestos: ["Líder de proyecto", "Desarrollado]
    }
]
```

Desde AngularJS filtrarías por valor de la propiedad "name"  (o una propiedad con ID) para obtener su respectivo vector de puestos.